# Nodejs remove last slash from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, response

Hi I have next url: `http://example.com`, when I put it in browser, browser add slash in the end like this: `http://example.com/`, how can I remove it? I'm using nodejs on server side. Thanks.

Comment: why you want to do this?

Comment: I need it to have a pretty url. Why? My manager want this thing :)

Comment: the browser adds the slash or the browser is redirected to `http://example.com/` ?

Comment: the browser adds the slash

Comment: what browser are you talking about? Neither Firefox nor Chrome has this behavior

Comment: Chrome and Safari. Firefox works fine.

Comment: I think you need to tell your manager to get a grip and worry about something else.

Comment: Search engines may index these pages separately. It's best to do 301 redirect to the canonical. Check out how to use canonical URLs in google webmaster tools guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

6 years and no answer... Well I faced a similar problem in a node app Im using socket.io and if the url has a tail slash the sockets wont work because some stupid CORS thing

however I figured how to redirect or set the location to the correct one

Note: I'm using Express and MVC architecture/pattern
but the solution can be tunned to fit your needs
So I placed this in my controller

```
 exports.myController = async (req, res, next)=>{
          
      if (req.originalUrl.endsWith('/')) {
        return res.status(301).location(`${req.baseUrl}`).render('myTemplate', {some: variables});
      }
    
     return res.status(200).render('myTemplate', {some: variables});

};
```